# Off-the-shelf Java widget for uploading LARGE files

Tags: java, upload

Is there an off-the-shelf large file loading widget that supports chunking/resume much like YouTube's? Is JUpload the only option?

Comment: I just need to upload one file, not a whole directory at a time

Answer (score 0):

I would generally use JUpload, unless there was some particular reason not to. Why does JUpload not work for you?